# How to remove padding from top of ListTile in Drawer?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I can not remove the indent from the first ListTile in any way. I think this is some kind of default indent, but I could not overcome it. Is it possible? Attached is the code and screenshot.

```
Drawer(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 88.0,
        width: 1000,
        child: DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Настройки',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: MainStyle.p.fontSize
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title:  Text(
                'Язык',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: MainStyle.p.fontSize
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                "Русский",
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {

                },
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title:  Text(
                'Выход',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: MainStyle.p.fontSize
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                exit();
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
      Container(
          child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      globalState.version,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.grey
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
          )
      ),
    ],
  ),
 )
);
```

[image]

*P.S. There is not any details, but StackOverflow make me write more text, because of "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to your `DrawerHeader`:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
```